# SHA256 hash in Python 2.2

Tags: python, sha256, python-2.2

I need to create a SHA256 hash in **Python 2.2**, but a don't found any way to do this. All I found is for Python 2.4 or higher.

Anyone has a ideia to how I can do this?

Comment: Does it have to be pure Python or could you call an external executable?

Comment: Also have you looked at https://github.com/thomdixon/pysha2? It's a pure Python implementation of sha256 for pre-hashlib Python (I haven't tested 2.2 yet)

Comment: Jason, I try but don't work. It depends to _sha256
I make a jar to create the hash, but it ins't the best way for the system

Comment: That is a local dependency, the sha256.py (https://github.com/thomdixon/pysha2/blob/master/sha2/sha256.py) class itself only depends on `copy, struct, sys` and it's use of `struct` doesn't use the Python 2.5 methods like `unpack_from`